# File.Exists() always returns false on IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, iis, file-permissions

The file path that I'm checking with File.Exists() resides on a mapped drive (`Z:\hello.txt`). The code runs fine in debug environment, however in IIS, it always returns false

```
var fullFileName = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FileName"], fileName);

if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullFileName))
```

Why is this so, and how can I workaround this?

I have granted everyone full read/write permissions in that mapped drive

EDIT:

I tried deleting the file via `\\192.168.1.12\Examples\Files\2.xml` and I get the same result. It doesn't detect the file on IIS, but works fine on debug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think your application do not has permission on "Z:"
Is "Z:" network disk?

Comment: The user `LocalSystem` (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) doesn't have network access AFAIK. If it's so, then "you" (your application) have to impersonate as another user.

Comment: Because ISS run on user: SYSTEM on your computer, so it can not access to Z: drive

Answer (score 2):

I have had similar issues using network mapped drives, when running debug code application works perfectly and when running release version application cannot find the file.

If the files are stored on the same server as the application is deployed we found a solution by storing the local drive directory location of the mapped drive for example `Z:\files\` could be `E:\folder\folder1\`

If the application is deployed on a separate server we found using the full network name works for example `\\server1\folder\`

I hope this proves helpful to you.

Comment: I just tried it. I am trying to delete my file with this path \\192.168.1.12\Examples\Files\2.xml - Same result. It works on VS's debug, but not when hosted in IIS.

Answer (score 2):

Your web application is running under a certain security context and you need to find out what context this is. If it's a normal user, open a command prompt as the user (using the `runas` tool), map the required drive using the command prompt (be sure to use the `/persistent:yes` flag)

Alternatively why can't you just use a UNC path (`\\serverName\shareName`) and avoid all this nonsense?

**EDIT: 2013-05-27**
To troubleshoot this, create a new application pool, based on whatever app pool you want. Then set the identity that this pool runs under as shown in the attached screenshot.

[image: Screenshot showing setting of IIS creds]

Make sure that this user has the correct privileges on the file share and then retest it

Comment: I just tried it. I am trying to delete my file with this path \\192.168.1.12\Examples\Files\2.xml - Same result. It works on VS's debug, but not when hosted in IIS.

Comment: What is the identity of the application pool your site is running under?

Answer (score 0):

May be you should use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar`